# Get struct values from List of class with foreach

Tags: c#, list, struct, foreach

I'm trying to get some values from a PLC (each value has a name and a int value) and save them for backup reasons on a PC.

So i got a Struct for the name and the int

```
public struct sValues
{
    public string ObjectName;
    public int Value;
}
```

As there are many values that I need to store I also got a class with all of them.

```
public class MemMainS
{
    public sValues svMode;
    public sValues svFreqOrBal;
    (...)
}
```

And a List of the Class

```
MemMainS mainCurrent = new MemMainS();
public List<MemMainS> TestList = new List<MemMainS>();
```

I also got some test values

```
private void SetTest()
{
    mainCurrent.svMode.ObjectName = "Obj1.Addr1";
    mainCurrent.svMode.Value = 1;

    mainCurrent.svFreqOrBal.ObjectName = "Obj2.Addr2";
    mainCurrent.svFreqOrBal.Value = 2;
}
```

When I try to get the data from the List with a foreach it's only possible if I tell the exact element of the List

```
foreach (var mv in TestList)
{
    FieldInfo[] listFields = mv.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public 
                                                  | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                  | BindingFlags.Instance);
    int j = 0;
    foreach (FieldInfo lf in listFields)
    {
        FieldInfo[] classFields = lf.FieldType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public
                                                       | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                       | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach(FieldInfo cf in classFields)
        {
            sValues sv;

            //sv = TestList.ElementAt(j);//Possible to get it working like this?

            sv = TestList.ElementAt(j).svMode;//Works for just svMode
            //Output:
            //Obj1.Addr1
            //1
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something that I didn't thought of yet? Or is it even possible?

If I try *sv = TestList.ElemntAt(j);* VS compiler tells me that the type is not the same but the type is of sValues as sv is.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'WinFormServer.Memory.MemMainS' to
>   'WinFormServer.Memory.sValues'

Comment: why are you using `ElementAt` *at all* here? you can go direct: `TestList[j].svMode`.

Comment: Are you trying to treat the named properties of type `sValues` in class `MemMainS` as a collection? (i.e. why the need for reflection)

Comment: I think you should take a step back and concentrate on your requirement: create a backup of a list of values (and possibly reload the data from the backup). Depending on the details, a variety of serialization techniques and databases could be the solution.

Comment: `TestList` is a collection of `MemMainS`, not `sValue`, so an element of that very list can't be stored in a variable of type `sValues` (like your `sv` variable). That's exactly what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you expect that line of code to work or what you expect it to do.  You have an object of type `MemMainS`, which contains many properties of type `sValues`.  If you *were* able to assign that entire object to a single object of type `sValues`, what would you expect it to contain?  The compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is.  Basically, a basket of apples is not an apple.  What's wrong with just using the approach that already works and just assigning each property?  Even if there are *many* of them, writing that code is a few moments of copy/paste.

Comment: There are multiple very questionable design issues in this code; I'm not saying you *can't* code like that, but all these public fields and mutable structs *are* going to bite you hard sooner or later. This is not idiomatic C#.

Comment: @David there are not just many of them, there are more than 1000, for different PLCs so this would just be too much to just copy and paste

Comment: @StefanKaim: Still doesn't sound like a problem.  There's nothing inherently wrong with a single operation having more than 1000 lines of code, as long as it's clear and simple.  Some basic text manipulation could produce the full code in less time than it's taking you to avoid producing the code.

Comment: @grek40 yes, it would be a lot easier to save everything in databeses, the PLCs just can't connect to a database. So I need to save the files as name and value

Comment: But the question is tagged C# ... can you program your PLC in C#? If not, what is your C# environment and why can't it connect a database? I was suspecting that you somehow transfer your data from the PLC to a separate C# program in a "normal" environment where you would have access to files and databases...

Comment: I got a dll to connect to the PLC and save everything on a PC
as writing values to the PLC and getting the values from it takes a lot of time it's really just for backup

Comment: But the C# code using that dll can also connect to a database, thus transferring the data without the need for a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest taking advantage of the indexer properties in .Net to modify the `MemMainS` class to behave just a little like a Dictionary collection, like this:

```
public class MemMainS
{
    private Dictionary<string, sValues> data = new Dictionary<string, sValues>();
    public ICollection<string> Keys {get {return data.Keys;} }

    public Dictionary<string, sValues>.ValueCollection.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return data.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public sValues this[string valueName] 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (data.ContainsKey(valueName)) return data[valueName];
            return default(sValues); // could opt to throw an exception here instead
        }
        set 
        {
            data[valueName] = value;
        }
    }

    public sValues svMode {get {return data["svMode"]; } set {data["svMode"] = value;} }
    public sValues svFreqOrBal {get {return data["svFreqOrBal "]; } set {data["svFreqOrBal "] = value;} };
   // (...)
}
```

That will let you re-write the loop like this to avoid reflection:

```
foreach (var mv in TestList)
{
    foreach(string item in mv.Keys)
    {
       sValues sv = mv[item];
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
foreach(var mv in TestList)
{
     foreach(sValues sv in mv)
     {
         //...
     }
}
```

The problem here is we don't know *which* sValue property we're looking at in those loops. We have the `ObjectName` address, but not the property name. It seems like those property names should be included in the struct data. You have a property name, like `svFreqOrBal`, that will have a 1:1 mapping to a ObjectName or address like `Obj2.Addr2`. There's no reason not to include that as part of the struct.

While I'm here, I suggest defining the struct using a simple immutable pattern this way:

```
public struct sValues
{
    public string ObjectName {get;private set;}
    public int Value {get; private set;}

    public sValues(string objectName, int Value)
    {
        ObjectName = objectName;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
}
```

(Of course, with the potential addition of the name property as suggested above).

Finally, seeing in the comments you have more than 1000 potential different PLC values, you may want to forgo the named properties in `MemMainS` entirely, and only use the Dictionary + indexer. Of course, this costs you some compile-time safety, but you can make up for some of this by getting a list or string[] of your valid PLC value names you can check against in the indexer for validation.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You list a `List<MemMainS>`; therefore the j'th element of the list is a `MemMainS`. You are trying to assign it to `sv`, a `sValues` value. That doesn't work by default; you *can* add an implicit conversion operator, but you really probably shouldn't. But if you search "C# overload implicit conversion operator" it'll show you how. It is much easier to just access the `.svMode` member of the j'th element.